# How to modify a different class field from a static method?

Tags: c#, methods, static-methods, non-static

I'm new to the C# world and I'm trying to create my first project.
I want to create application that read Ant+ heart rate sensors and analyze the data received.
I've created 2 classes

```
public class Athlete
    { 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int HBrate { get; set; }
        public int HBcount { get; set; }
        }
    }
public class AntSensor
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SensorID { get; set; }
        public byte ChannelNr { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After selecting the Athlete and the sensor from a UI I initialize the Heart Rate sensor and open the receiver channel

```
public void AthleteStart()
        {
            if ((AthleteSelected != null) || (ANTSensorSelected != null))
            {

                AthleteLabelTxt = $"{AthleteSelected.Name}";
                ANT_Device device0 = new ANT_Device();
                ANT_Channel channel0 = device0.getChannel(0x00);
                HRProject.AntApps(AthleteSelected, device0, channel0, new string[0]);
            }
        }
```

then after some code that control the communication protocol I have:

```
static void DeviceResponse(ANT_Response response)
        {
            // some code to control the response 
            // and the a call to Update my sensor data
            SensorUpdate(response.getDataPayload());
          
        }
```

how I can put here some code that update HBrate or HBcount on my AthleteSelected or ANTSensorSelected?

Comment: You dont use the `ANTSensorSelected` in your `AthleteStart` method. You also dont show us the `ANT_Response` class or the `getDataPayload` method(and what it returns). It's not clear what you are trying and why you are failing

Comment: thanks you for your answer. let me add more details.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Schmelter already commented: The given information are not that much useful to find out at which point you are failing.

But to try to answer your question in a more general manner:
Updating a class (but you mean a class-instance) property from a static method, requires to give the class instance as a parameter to that method.

```
public class MyInstanceClass
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}

public static class MyStaticClass
{
    public static void DoSomething(MyInstanceClass instance)
    {
         instance.MyValue = "New Value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `ANTSensorSelected` because I was thinking to update directly `AthleteSelected` but if need I can eventually add.
for the communication I'm using the `ANT_Managed_Library` from Garmin here the `ANT_Response` class:

```
public class ANT_Response
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The object that created this response (ie: The corresponding ANTChannel or ANTDevice instance).
        /// </summary>
        public object sender;

        /// <summary>
        /// The channel parameter received in the message. Note: For some messages this is not applicable.
        /// </summary>
        public byte antChannel;

        /// <summary>
        /// The time the message was received.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime timeReceived;

        /// <summary>
        /// The MessageID of the response
        /// </summary>
        public byte responseID;

        /// <summary>
        /// The raw contents of the response message
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] messageContents;

        internal ANT_Response(object sender, byte antChannel, DateTime timeReceived, byte IDcode, byte[] messageContents)
        {
            this.sender = sender;
            this.antChannel = antChannel;
            this.timeReceived = timeReceived;
            this.responseID = IDcode;
            this.messageContents = messageContents;
        }
```

The code it's quite long let me try to add the most significant parts:

```
channel0.channelResponse += new dChannelResponseHandler(ChannelResponse); // Add channel response function to receive channel event messages

/// Delegate for Channel Response Event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">Message details received from device</param>
    public delegate void dChannelResponseHandler(byte antChannel, ANT_Response response);
```

here the `ChannelResponse`

```
static void ChannelResponse(byte antChannel, ANT_Response response)
        {
            
            try
            {
                switch ((ANT_ReferenceLibrary.ANTMessageID)response.responseID)
                {
                    case ANT_ReferenceLibrary.ANTMessageID.RESPONSE_EVENT_0x40:
 //some extra code with more cases
  SensorUpdate(response.getDataPayload());
```

here the `getDataPayLoad`

```
/// Returns the 8-byte data payload of an ANT message. Throws an exception if this is not a received message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
      public byte[] getDataPayload()
        {
            if (messageContents.Length == 9
                && (responseID == (byte)ANT_ReferenceLibrary.ANTMessageID.BROADCAST_DATA_0x4E
                     || responseID == (byte)ANT_ReferenceLibrary.ANTMessageID.ACKNOWLEDGED_DATA_0x4F
                     || responseID == (byte)ANT_ReferenceLibrary.ANTMessageID.BURST_DATA_0x50
               ))
                return messageContents.Skip(1).ToArray();   //Just skip the channel byte and return the payload
            else
                return splitExtMessage(extMsgParts.DataPayload);    // Extended message
        }
```